# How to mock cookie method with jest and superTest?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I am writing an application and I needed to mock the tests on the users endpoint. I created a middleware function which returns a user cookie. Question is how do I achieve this with jest?

Here is my `login-helper.js` code where the `loginHelper()` function needs to be called to return a cookie before each test

```js
const loginHelper = async (request, email, password) => {
  const userParams = {email: '', password: ''};
  
  if (!(email && password)) {
    await request
        .post(`/api/v1/users`)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send(userParams);
  }

  email = email || userParams.email;
  password = password || userParams.password;

  const loginResponse = await request
      .post(`/api/v1/users/login`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .send({email: email, password: password});

  return loginResponse.headers['set-cookie'];
};


module.exports.loginHelper = loginHelper;
```

The `update-user.test.js` test code looks like this.

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const {loginHelper} = require('../login-helper');
const setupDb = require('../test-setup');
const User = require('../models/user');

const request = supertest(app);
setupDb();

describe('Update a user: PUT /users/:id', () => {
  const userParams = {};

  const updatedUserParams = {};

  let user;
  let cookie;

  beforeEach(async ()=> {
    const response = await request
        .post('/api/v1/users')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send(userParams);

    user = response.body;
    cookie = await loginHelper(request);
  });


  it('should update a user when user is verified', async (done) => {
    const savedUser = await User.findById(user._id).select('verificationToken');

    await request
        .post(`/api/v1/users/${user._id}/verify`)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send({token: savedUser.verificationToken});

    const response = await request
        .put(`/api/v1/users/${user._id}`)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('cookie', cookie)
        .send(updatedUserParams);
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);

    const responseUser = response.body;
    expect(responseUser.email).toEqual(userParams.email.toLowerCase());
    expect(responseUser.name).toEqual(updatedUserParams.name);

    done();
  });
});
```

I understand I need to mock the cookie as it's undefined.

Does anyone have an idea how i could mock the cookie on the test with the `login-helper` function as in `beforeEach`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using **agent** from supertest. ensure the routes are in one test suite

```
import supertest from "supertest";

const agent = supertest.agent("your baseurl here e.g localhost:8000")

describe("Authorization", () => {
    it("POST /auth", async () => {
        const user = {
            username: "user",
            password: "abc1234",
        };
        const res = await agent.post("/auth").send(user);
        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    });

    it("GET /show", async () => {
        const res = await agent.get("/show");
        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    });
});
```